C# IMemoryCache: append to list in one operation?
I'm using an IMemoryCache (Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory) in a ASP.NET Core 9 project. I'm storing a List<string> in that cache, and would like to add a value to that list.
This seems to require that I:

Pull the list from the cache
Copy it into a new list
Append the value
Set the updated list back in the cache.

var cacheKey = CacheKey(document.Resource.PartitionKey());
var idsList = _memoryCache.Get(cacheKey) as List<string>;

if (idsList != null)
{
    var listCopy = new List<string>(idsList);
    idsList.Add(document.Resource.Id);
    _memoryCache.Set(cacheKey, listCopy);
}

This seems to create an opportunity for a race condition. Is the best path forward to implement my own thread lock around these operations? Or is there a simpler approach?
Thanks for any suggestions.

you might be able to get better answers if you specify what you are using this list for.

What is contained in this list?

A list of document ids, potentially saving me a trip to my database.

Use a HashSet then.

you can store a ConcurrentBag instead of a list, a ConcurrentBag can be updated from multiple threads concurrently without race conditions. the downside is that this bag is copied into a List when iterating (foreach loop), which may be expensive for large lists.
otherwise, if you want fast iteration you can store a List in the cache and a Lock, the lock will be held only by the thread copying and replacing (after copying the old values, as per your current code) the old list in the cache to avoid racing with another writer doing the same operations, read-only readers can read the old list from the cache without taking this lock as the cache is thread-safe.

Thanks Ahmed. If I use a ConcurrentBag, would it still be multiple operations to retrieve the object from the memory cache, update it, and set the new object? If so, I suppose it makes sense to just implement my own lock around these operations (for writes only, as you suggest).

@BenjiFB if you use ConcurrentBag then you don't need to set a new object in the cache, there is only ever one bag that you can concurrently call Add or Clear on, and every reader will get the updated version on the next call to GetEnumerator (in a foreach loop).

That makes sense. Thank you!

If you're using locking make sure you don't lock all objects but only for that cache key. For this consider using a keyed locking library.

@MarkCiliaVincenti Or just create a class that holds a lock and a volatile list .... you don't need a library for that
